# Stop island rotation when using unwrap in the uv editor?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am working on a function that will make it possible to cut the islands in realtime in the uv editor. The idea is to be able to skip the seam step completely. I have already got this function to work, the problem is that as soon as you unwrap something in Blender the islands get's rotated. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: I guess this functionality is part of the C code ...

Comment: Does that mean it is more or less impossible to fix in Python?

Comment: That's what i meant, sorry ^^

Comment: I have never hired a programmer that have helped me write anything in C, if i understand this correctly it more or less means that you have to "brake" Blender and makes it impossible to update once new code arrives from another update is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The change will not be part of your addon. You would need to recompile Blender, and provide this recompiled Blender version then.